# Replacing character in the string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to enter in the array two ` backqoutes. But it enters single quote. Could you please help me here ?

Input:

```
abc"cde"fgh"ijkl"
```

Ouput:

```
abc``cde''fgh``ijkl''
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mystr;
    long int i=0,j=0,l;
    while(getline (cin, mystr))
    {
        // l=strlen(mystr);
        l=mystr.length();
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if (mystr[i]=='"')
            {
                j=j+1;
                if(j%2==1)
                    mystr[i]='``'; //Problem is here
                else
                    mystr[i]='"';
            }
        }
        cout << mystr;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Srry for my bad mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is C++. However the "``" is not a char but 2 char. Use concatenation instead like

```
   Result += "``";
```